# Google Sheets DateTime static vs dynamic dates issues

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, datetime-format, utc, custom-function

## Summary

I have been working in Google Sheets with timezones and I have found a perplexing issue that I cannot figure out. Basically, if I use a custom script formula on a static date or a dynamically-generated date, I get different results, when it should be the same!

## What I have

[image]
Here is a quick preview that shows what I am talking about. `C2` is a dynamically-created Date while `C5` is a static Date. I have created a custom function that will take a `TimeDateString` such as `C2` and `C5` and convert it to another Time Zone.

You can clearly see that `D2` and `D5` are **different** answers; however, they should be the same. **This is the reason for this question. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?**

## Spreadsheet Link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HEFud8oqM-Yx0BR5SjyEG8yjGK-O0t8c6YcEfYtnLSA/edit?usp=sharing

## Code

#### Custom Script Function

```
function DateTime(dateTimeString, timeZone, format) {

  if (format == null)   { format = "MMM dd 'at' hh:mma z" }
  if (timeZone == null) { timeZone = "GMT" }

  var date_time = new Date(dateTimeString);

  if(!isNaN(date_time.valueOf())) {
    return Utilities.formatDate(date_time, timeZone, format);
  } else {
    throw Utilities.formatString('Invalid Date String: "%s"', dateTimeString);
  }

}
```

#### `C2` Formula

```
=CONCATENATE(Month($A2), "/", if(Day($A2) < 10, CONCAT("0", Day($A2))), "/", Year($A2), " ", Hour($B2), ":", if(Minute($B2) < 10, CONCAT("0", MINUTE($B2)), Minute($B2)))
```

#### `D2` Formula

```
=DateTime(C2)
```

#### `D5` Formula

```
=DateTime(C5)
```

Comment: @pnuts Can you please make that comment [about my script being in the wrong timezone] an adequate answer, because it solved my issue (I made no other suggested changes). I would like to reward you. I have not tried your `A2 + B2` suggestion, but might later on now that it works (I tried before, but it wasn't working)

Comment: I HAD changed my spreadsheet to use the `GMT` Timezone but did not realize the script had the same kind of setting. Your link states that it is a common source of issues

Comment: @pnuts your suggestion to `A2 + B2` works perfectly and looks much better

Comment: @pnuts I created a new answer as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Different Timezones

The comment suggested by the user `pnuts` was absolutely related to the reason for my strange behavior. I had modified my Spreadsheet timezone to be `GMT+0:00`; however, my script timezone remained at `GMT+9:00` **After making these two the same value, my sheet and the script worked correctly.**

There are actually 2 Timezones that you need to review, **and they need to match!!**

1. **Spreadsheet's Timezone** *(`File > Spreadsheet settings > Timezone`)*
2. **Script's Timezone** *(`File > Project properties > Timezone`)*

> **Note:** these two Timezones have to match!!
>
> *Otherwise, you will get strange results as shown in the question.*

## Further Action You Can Do

Google has admitted that this is a common source of issues, I have created an `issue` in there `Google App Script Issue Tracker` and you can vote on this **open issue** if you have experienced this issue first-hand.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73046652

---

## Supporting Documentation & Citations

#### Google App Script Documentation

Google App Scripts [`Session`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()) documentation for the timezone information stated the following...

> Spreadsheet time zones that differ from the script time zone are a frequent source of scripting bugs.

#### Pnuts' Comment

As [**Pnuts** has stated in the comment to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648995/google-sheets-datetime-static-vs-dynamic-dates-issues?noredirect=1#comment84299539_48648995)...

> Timezone for the script is Tokyo. Seems your formula could be =text(A2+B2,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

**Note 1:** he stated that he [didn't want to make his comment an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648995/google-sheets-datetime-static-vs-dynamic-dates-issues?noredirect=1#comment84534129_48648995) and instead wanted me to write one.

**Note 2:** he was also correct in the `A2 + B2` modification.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you enter a date (static date), It's automatically converted into a number by Sheets (or Excel for that matter). So, `ISTEXT()` C2 is TRUE, While  C5 is FALSE.

Although to the naked eye,C5 seems to be the same text as C2,C5 is possibly sent in a different format to the script.  To see the actual format, Check the logs of the below script

```
function checkdatevalues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));
  var range = sheet.getRange('C2:C5');
  Logger.log(range.getValues());
}
```

Possible solutions:

- Prefix Static dates with `'` ; This will prevent Sheets from converting it into date value. `'11/6/2018 13:00`

Or

- Multiply Dynamic dates by 1; So, =`1*CONCATENATE(....)` and then format it into the required format in the menu.